# Python mixin with dynamic method names

Tags: python

Supposing I have the following classes:

```
class SomeMixin:
    def apply(self):
        pass

class Foo(SomeMixin):
    pass

class Bar(SomeMixin):
    pass
```

How do I implement `SomeMixin` so that the attached method `apply` becomes `apply_foo` in `Foo` and `apply_bar` in `Bar`? The methods in the mixin follows a generic algorithm, but the generated names matter to the framework I'm using.

Comment: Where is `sort` coming into this?

Comment: Actually I renamed the method to `apply`. This method performs a computation that relies on the subclasses' attributes. The attributes needed can be declared as a list of names in the subclass so it can be use by the mixin.

Comment: The fact that generated names matter and that this seems a little odd: I'm suspecting this may be an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: The generated names matter because they get mapped to attributes in a database table.

Comment: Care to name the framework and give a slightly more concrete example ? As Jon Clements mentions we obviously have a XY problem here and mixins are possibly / probably not the solution (or only part of it).

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't do that in the mixin, but in the concrete classes themselves. Just define the methods so that they call `apply` directly.

```
class Foo(SomeMixin):
    def apply_foo(self):
        return self.apply()

class Bar(SomeMixin):
    def apply_bar(self):
        return self.apply()
```